# Преобразовать матрицу с++

Tags: c++

У меня есть матрица, которая показывает из какой вершины можно попасть в какую. Так же будем считать, что из i-ой вершины можно попасть в i-ю вершину.Матрица на входе (жирным выделены № вершин):
**n 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10**
**1** 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
**2** 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 1
**3** 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
**4** 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0
**5** 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0
**6** 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
**7** 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
**8** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
**9** 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
Я пытаюсь построить матрицу, которая будет показывать все пути из каждой точки, например:
первый путь будет таким: **1->4->5->8->9->10**
(т.е. мы из пункта 1 переходим в пункт 4, из 4 ближайший пункт 5, в 5-ом ближайший 8 и т. д).
второй: **1->7->10**
*поскольку из 1 в 4 мы уже ходили, идём из 1 в 7, а из 7 сразу в 10)*
и так по порядку, сначала смотрим все пути с началом в пункте 1, потом с началом в пункте 2 и.д.
Это должно будет превратиться в такую матрицу:
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
. . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
. . . . . . . . . . . . .  . . .
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1
Мой алгоритм действий: Ищем в строке первую единицу кроме начальной (потому что это точка отправления), приравниваем её к 0 и переходим на строчку под её номером, т.е., если **a[j-столбец][i-строка] == 1**, переходим на **a[i][i]** и так дальше.
Если совсем грубо, выглядит это примерно так:

```
 //выше будет цикл, который будет обнулять z для того, чтобы каждый раз возвращаться к началу матрицы
    for (int j = z; j < n; j++) {
                for (int i = j+1; i < m; i++) {//i=j+1, чтобы не считать первую единицу строки
                    cout << matrix[j][i] << " ";
                    if (matrix[j][i] == 1){ //Если элемент матрицы равен 1, то..
                        if(ty==0) //ty нужен для того, чтобы удалить только первую встречную 1, т.к. если удалять все 1 будут проблемы
                            matrix[j][i] = 0; //приравниваем эту единицу к 0
                        ty = 1; // теперь ty = 1 и мы не будем в этой итерации больше приравнивать значения к 0
                        j = i; //Теперь j=i , т.е. если мы нашли, что значение 1 было на 5 пункте то переходим на 5 строку
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Надеюсь смысл уловить можно. Прошу посоветовать, как лучше поправить код. *После двух-летнего перерыва тяжело возвращаться к с++* :(

**UPD:** поправил код, стало лучше, но всё равно ещё не то

```
for(int x=0;x<20;x++){ //поставил х = 20, чтобы не было слишком много строк
    ty = 0; // принимает значения 0/1, если 0, то мы, ещё не нашли первую вершину равную 1, не считая изначальной 
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (int i = j+1; i < m; i++) { //i = j+1 для того, чтобы не считать изначальную
            if (matrix[j][i - 1] == 1 && ty == 0) {
                cout << " |1| "; //для наглядности, показывает начальную вершину
            }
            cout << matrix[j][i] << " ";
            if (matrix[j][i] == 1){
                if (ty == 0) {
                    matrix[j][i] = 0; //приравниваем первую найденную 1 к 0, чтобы не повторяться
                    ty = 1; //приравниваем оператор к 1, только как мы закончим с первой строкой новой матрицы, обнулим это значение
                }
                cout << "|" << j+1 << i+1 << "| "; //показываем координаты вершины, которая равна 1 (начинаем не с 0, а с 1)
                j = i-1;
                break;
            }
            cout << matrix[j][i] << " ";
 
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Проблема в том, что дублируются первые строки.
**Код с результатом тут:**
http://cpp.sh/9sypz

**UPD2**:Опишу точнее:

```
1->4->5->8->9->10 
1->7->10   
1->10
```

из первого пункта мы перебрали все пути, теперь смотрим из второго

```
2->3->8->9->10  
2->4->5->8->9->10  
2->5->8->9->10  
2->7->10  
2->10
```

из 2 пункта тоже всё перебрали

```
3->8->9->10
```

и т. д.
В матричном виде это будет выглядеть так:
1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1

**UPD3:** Решил протестировать с выводом, вместо матрицы я вывожу пути, и можно заметить, что алгоритм работает, только я никак не могу сообразить это грамотно перевести в матрицу http://cpp.sh/25yme

Comment: Я не понял задачу.

Comment: Попробую лучше объяснить, начнём со строк, строка показывает в какие вершины можно попасть из неё, например, из первой можно попасть напрямую в 4, 7 10 (так же в саму себя), из второй можно попасть в 3, 4, 5, 7,10 и так далее. Так вот,мне надо перебрать все возможные пути из каждой вершины, пример первых двух я привёл, могу дополнить в посте

Comment: Что такое матрица смежности - я знаю. А что здесь имеется в виду под всеми путями - непонятно.  Почему все примеры кончаются в 10? Все простые пути из каждой вершины в десятую? Или что?

Comment: Это пример, вершин может быть как 10, так и 100. А найти надо все пути из каждой вершины, причём не обязательно в 10 (конечную) вершину, просто в примере, который я привёл, все пути ведут в 10, а так, возможно путь будет заканчиваться  на 4-й или на 7-й вершине. Надеюсь, хотя бы немного прояснил суть вопроса?

Comment: а если у вас цикл будет?

Comment: Цикла, видимо, нет. Все ребра ведут в вершины с большими номерами.

Comment: Нужны именно пути? Или матрица (транзитивного замыкания)?

Comment: Почему в матрице у вас есть путь `2->1`? Это не возможно.

Comment: stanislav-volodarskiy, мне нужна матрица путей, но я пытаюсь её построить используя пути. Например, путь 1->3->6 ( при количестве вершин равном 7-и ) в матрицы будет выглядеть вот так:             `1 0 1 0 0 1 0`.

Comment: `Почему в матрице у вас есть путь 2->1`, что-то не могу найти, где это